# Open files as Tabs instead of Dropdown in jEdit

Tags: jedit

I'm using jEdit as a text-editor, but something that bugs me about it is that I can't find a way to have the standard dropdown-list become a series of tabs, which I find to give a much better overview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin for that. BufferTabs I believe is the name of it, and you can install it from the plugin manager. You then also have to enable it in your plugin manager to be on by default.

Comment: This works. Had a little trouble with it. Didn't expect the tabs to show up at the bottom.

Comment: You can configure the docking location of Plugins under the global Options menu item in the top dropdown menu.

Comment: Also useful with this plugin (on Mac OS X, not sure about other systems) -- change focus to the next/previous buffer with: COMMAND + PageDown/PageUp.  If using a MacBook without PageUp/Down keys, these key combinations work: fn + COMMAND + DownArrow/UpArrow